# Assign contactTestBitMask to <Set>

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, set, collision, bitmask

In SpriteKit I wish to assign the contactTestBitMask value to a set of values.

This is the normal way:

```
sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.goal.rawValue | ColliderType.greyBox.rawValue
```

meaning my sprite notifies me when it comes it contact with these collider types.
However my problem is that my collider types will be dynamically changing during gameplay and the sprite contactTestBitMask also needs to be changed. I was thinking of using a set collider types and assigning different sets and appropriated times:

```
sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = SetManager.sharedSetManager.normalSet
```

In SetManager Class:

```
    enum NormalColliderType:UInt32 {
    case greyBox = 0
    case enemy = 2
    case goal = 4
    case coin = 8
    }

var currentSet: Set<Int> = []

var normalSet: Set<UInt32> = [NormalColliderType.greyBox.rawValue | NormalColliderType.goal.rawValue]

static let sharedSetManager = SetManager()
```

Theoretically, its doable but the only error I'm receiving is:
"Cannot assign value of type 'Set' to type 'UInt32'"
I guess I'm asking how a set can be used as a variable

Comment: You can add a `greyBoxAndGoal` case to your `enum` with value of 5 (`greyBox` should be 1 not 0).

Answer (score 2):

`contactTestBitMask` is of [type UInt32](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/contactTestBitMask), so the type of `normalSet` can be just `UInt32`, and you can store it as so.

```
var normalSet: UInt32 = NormalColliderType.greyBox.rawValue | NormalColliderType.goal.rawValue
```

Comment: To add to this, I would create a dictionary of UInt32 so that you are not creating a ton of variables.  let collisionTypes = [UInt](); collisionTypes["normalSet"] = NormalColliderType.greyBox.rawValue | NormalColliderType.goal.rawValue;

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can set and clear individual collision and contact bits for specific categories using the bitwise AND and NOT operators, without affecting any other bits:

Turn off a specific contact (or collision) :

```
sprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask &= ~ColliderType.goal.rawValue
```

sprite contacts with the goal will no longer be notfied.

turn on a specific contact/colission:

```
   sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= ColliderType.newItem.rawValue
```

sprite will now collide with the `newItem`

Comment: For simple changes I would take this approach (only changing 1 category at a time), but for multiple category swapping,  I would predefine the sets like the other answer to avoid any chance of error when swapping the categories.